# Android org.apache.http.HttpResponse - which jar to include?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm getting this error in Eclipse:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for org.apache.http.HttpResponse. Fix the build
>   path then try building this project   mopub-sdk       Unknown Java Problem

What jar must be included to fix that?

Comment: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html

Comment: I had to add 2 jar files to the project (httpcore, httpclient, over 1 MB in size). Just wondering if it is possible to fix compiler errors with less libraries.

Comment: httpcore is required by httpclient, so I don't think so... If you used Gradle, then you only would see httpclient because it has transitive dependencies